# Natural hazards in California - Historic time series, spatial resolution (lat/long) & Climate Model Forecasts

Tags: data-request, weather, time-series

I am looking for a rather **high resolution data** set in tabular form (no shapefile, a .txt, .csv, or .dbf) on certain **natural hazards in California**.

The natural hazards I am particularly interested in are **drought** and **flood**. Along these lines I look for variables of something like

- Precipitation
- Soil Moisture
- Drought Indices
- Days of Extreme Heat
- Temperatures
- Baseflow
- Risk indices for drought/flood
- Risk for wild fire
- Coastal Flooding
- Area flooded if sea level rises
- Population of people affected by drought/flood

The number of variables should be >6. The background is I want to illustrate a new statistical method.

The data set should consist any of the following

1. A **spatial historical time series**.
2. A **spatial times series of projections** (e.g. A2 or B1 scenarios of IPCC, some bias-reduced downscaled projection or so).

For this lower the resolution, the better (say from a 5x5 km grid in lattitude longitude and daily values from 2000 onwards or so). I would however also be fine however with annual (or even more coarse resolution) data on census block or county level.

I've been looking at a couple of non-profit and governmental websites. But most data were either in form of maps or didn't meet the above criteria. Whenever I found data meeting the above criteria, I usually hit some authorization dialogue.

The closest I got to what I wanted was [Cal-Adapt](http://cal-adapt.org), the map on [precipitation](http://cal-adapt.org/precip/decadal/) is a perfect example of the data that I'd like to have in tabular form.

They have a section [tabular data downloads](http://cal-adapt.org/data/tabular/) which **would be exactly** what I need, if it were not for the mildly irritating fact that one has to select grid cells to download the data for. Since I want all of the data I'd have to click on all the cells, which - with a resolution of a 12km x 12km and the size of CA being 423,970 km^2 - is rather tedious. But this means these data are out there and they are made available to the public, I just need the raw data (or an equivalent).

I'm also aware of [these data sets](http://www.globalchange.gov/browse/datasets) but didn't have the time to investigate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the content at [Data Basin](http://databasin.org), which has a lot of California data.

Comment: Perhaps you can expand this answer?